# Lists are not currently supported in HTML input in rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-1.9

I wanted to design an api for creating a rent information along with gallery(multiple image upload).My models look this

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    ownerName = models.CharField(_("Owner's Name"),max_length=255, blank=True,null=True,
        help_text=_("Owner's Full Name"))
    renter = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=120,blank=True,null=True)
    phoneNumber = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False,null=True,
        help_text=_("Phone number of contact person"))

class Gallery(models.Model):
    rental = models.ForeignKey('Rental', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name=_('Rental'), related_name="gallery")
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True,upload_to='upload/',null=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class GalleryListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Gallery

class RentalCreateUpdateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    gallery = GalleryListSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Rental
        exclude = ('id','slug','is_published','created_on','modified_on',)
```

**views.py**

```
class RentalCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Rental.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RentalCreateUpdateSerializer
    # permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def create(self,validated_data):
        ownerName=validated_data.get('ownerName',None)
        renter = validated_data.get('renter', None)
        email=validated_data.get('email',None)
        phoneNumber=validated_data.get('phoneNumber',None)
        image=validated_data.pop('image')
        return Rental.objects.create(ownerName=ownerName,renter=renter,phoneNumber=phoneNumber,email=email,image=image)
```

How can i enable multiple image upload for each rent? what i get is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear whether you are asking about a file upload FORM within the Browsable API Renderer, or if you are asking purely about the plumbing within Django to save and display Images. I'm answering regarding the plumbing, i.e. uploading and saving.

Tutorial for uploading files using REST API, maybe read this over to get better background first: https://medium.com/@jxstanford/django-rest-framework-file-upload-e4bc8de669c0#.i5pun7abs

Notice how they set the Parsers in the FileUploadViewSet. This FileUpload model is like your Gallery model. You should be able to add parser_classes to your CreateAPIView like this:

```
# views.py
from rest_framework.parsers import FormParser, MultiPartParser
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from probably.obtain.models import FileUpload
from probably.obtain.serializers import FileUploadSerializer


class FileUploadViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    queryset = FileUpload.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FileUploadSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user,
                       datafile=self.request.data.get('datafile'))
```

Read this for more detailed information on how/when to choose your parser, and some more snippets: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/

Comment: I think he's asking about how to upload multiple images through the UI.